# Java JTable shortcuts not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, shortcut

It's my first time using a **JTable** and I'm having a problem.
I have been testing my JTable with a main method like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame(APP_TITLE);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
                f.setContentPane(fileManager);

                f.setIconImage(Icons.SOFTWARE_ICON.getImage());

                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

And everything works perfectly. I'm able to press the shortcuts (UP, DOWN and CTRL+A) and they all work.

But now I've been adding the FileManager (JPanel) to my UI (JFrame) like this :

```
public FileManager fMan = new FileManager();
```

[...]

```
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();

splitPane.setLeftComponent(fMan);
```

And now, I noticed two things :

- The shortcuts aren't working
- The colors aren't automatically inverted on selection

[image: Works perfectly]

[image: Doesnt work]

I tried *requesting the focus*, *changing the theme*, and neither helped.

Comment: Try to find where the focus point is. It is not obviously on the table, there you think it is.

Comment: *getMostRecentFocusOwner().getClass()* returns **javax.swing.JTable**

Comment: Run the application. Check focus. Use the tab key

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Note first test using a basic table: `splitPane.setLeftComponent( new JScrollPane( new JTable(3,5) ) );
`. Once you get this working then try your custom table. This way you will know if the problem is your table or the JDK table.

Comment: Okay, I did what you told me and it doesn't work, I will post an example ASAP

Answer (score 0):

After over 5 hours of trying to fix this, I finally can proudly say **I HAVE FOUND THE ANSWER**!

A subclass used this code :

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
            }

        });
```

And it is causing the JTable to not receive the imputs properly.

Oh well! :)