# Java resizing window including a JSplitPane : fixed size panel?

Tags: java, swing, resize, splitpane

I have a JSplitpane in my software and two JPanels inside it, and I would like the height of the divider to ajust with the screen resize

Heres what happen when I resize :

[image: SplitPane]

I have been looking everywhere for this and I know it must be easy to fix but I could not find it.

Comment: Without trying anything, I would say you need is somewhat complicated. I'd start by trapping the `componentResized` event of the parent container and the `propertyChange` event for the separator.  You want to get the `dividerLocation` and calculate the percentage of the available height it's using. When `componentResized` is called, you then want to update the `dividerLocation` with this information - the trick is going to be known when the user updates the `dividerLocation` and when the program does it

Comment: (1-) See your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162625/java-jtable-shortcuts-not-working. You were asked to post an [mcve] that demonstrated the problem. That helped you solve your last problem and it will help you solve this problem. We can't possibly guess what your code is doing based on an image. `I would like the height of the divider to ajust with the screen resize` - this should happen automatically. JSplitPane provides a method for you to specify how to allocate space when the size changes.

Comment: I disagree, first, I didn't post a Minimal Complete and Verifiable example on my last post and second no one needs to read any code, it's just basic Java UI shenanigans. Now, for the actual part I need, wheres the 'method that specify how to allocate space when the size changes'? It would be great to not have to do what MadProgrammer said that was needed to do.

Comment: `I didn't post a Minimal Complete and Verifiable example on my last post` - I know you didn't.  You were asked to post on because one should be posted with every question. `no one needs to read any code` - if you our help to solve the problem you do. The solution to your last problem was some hidden code that nobody on the forum have guessed was being used. So we can only assume we have the same problem here. Either the problem is the split pane or the layout manager of your frame. We don't have `5 hours to waste` guessing what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: `wheres the 'method...` - you can read the API, I forget the exact name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Link to the API/Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setResizeWeight(double))

Required code :

**splitPane.setResizeWeight(1);**

Explanation :

> A value of 0, the default, indicates the right/bottom component gets
>   all the extra space 
>       (the left/top component acts fixed), where as a value of 1 specifies the 
>       left/top component gets all the extra space (the right/bottom component acts
>       fixed). Specifically, the left/top component gets (weight * diff) extra space
>       and the right/bottom component gets (1 - weight) * diff extra space.